# Programatically filter web content by scope in Liferay 6.2.GA2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, web-content

Updating to have more info:
Is there any way to programatically select all the web content from global scope or currently selected site scope.

I want to do this in velocity template "portal_normal.vm". I wrote "$themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId().toString()" to get group id.

I have 2 sites/communities and I have assigned one user to each of them. One site is default liferay site which has default liferay user.Other site is my custom site and has my own user. When I try to login with each of them ,I always get group id of liferay site.Is there any other method I need to use to get site of current logged in user?

Comment: what do you mean by selecting all webcontent?

Comment: Also please provide what all efforts you have given for it/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must allow the usage of `ServiceLocator` in your Velocity templates. In your `portal-ext.properties` set the following:

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

If you already have these keys set, just remove `serviceLocator` from the list.

Using `serviceLocator` we can load `GroupLocalServiceUtil` and `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil`. Its very simple to obtain all the sites WebContent:

```
#set ($journal_article_local_service = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.JournalArticleLocalService"))

#set ($journal_articles = $journal_article_local_service.getArticles($theme_display.getScopeGroupId()))
```

To get all the ones in the global scope:

For the global group:

```
#set ($group_local_service = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalService"))

#set ($global_group = $group_local_service.getGroup($theme_display.getCompanyId(), "Global"))

#set ($journal_article_local_service = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.JournalArticleLocalService"))

#set ($journal_articles = $journal_article_local_service.getArticles($global_group.getGroupId()))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Actually I want to do this in velocity template "portal_normal.vm". 
I wrote "$themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId().toString()" to get group id.I have 2 sites/communities in my liferay and have assigned one user to each of them.
One site is default liferay site which has default liferay user.Other site is my custom site and has my own user.
When I try to login with each of them ,I always get group id  of liferay site.Is there any other method I need to use to get site  of current logged in user?

Comment: No problem! For the rest of the community please update the question to reflect your comment. I'll update it.

Comment: thank you so much for this.I will try this code and will update as soon as I test.If I understand it correctly "$themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()." is going to return the site id of current logged in user right?

Comment: It will return the groupId of the site the user is currently viewing.

Comment: I tried to get community id using "getScopeGroupId"  ,but I always get default liferay community/site id back.When I login with user who has my custom site/community assigned I am expecting its id to be returned.Any clue why that might be happening? Also when I try to get articles I get the articles with all its version where I am looking for only the latest version of the article.Should I be removing duplicates on my own?

Comment: @manni, `getScopeGroupId` gets the site that the user is viewing. You would need to obtain the `groupId` for your site differently. For instance, you can get a list of all `groupIds` of a user by calling `user.getGroupIds()`.

Comment: Thank you,I tried getting groups of the current user using this method.Then,for all the groups I check whether its a community (using isRegularSite api).If its a community I fetch all the articles for that groupid and use these article id to dynamically add content using web content display portlet in "portal_normal.vm".For some reason,I am getting the correct article id but not able to render them in web content display portlet.This works fine for default liferay site scope and able to render all the content in Liferay site.What could be the reason its not rendering my custom site content?